# Will a String Get-only Lambda property always return a new object, or is it cached?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a class I called FileFilter.  It is a pretty basic class, whose goal is to facilitate creation of the file filters for file browsing dialogs.

```
Class FileFilter{

Public Name { get; }
Public Extension { get; }
Public FileFilter => String.Format(“{0}{1}|{1}”, Name, Extension);

}
```

I don’t anticipate having to access the ‘FileFilter’ property a lot (only when using the dialogs), but figured I could use the object to store the strings for other functions, such as DirectoryInfoGetFiles() could accept the file extension.

So I’ve created a small static class with the various objects, such as ‘TextFile *.txt’

My question here is theoretically speaking, is it more efficient to generate the string for FileFilter during object construction, or to use that lambda expression?

If using the lambda expression several times in a row, are new instances created, or is it cached?

I think it would create a new string on first use, store it and reuse it during runtime since it’s always generating the same string, but don’t actually know. OTOH, it’s technically a function, that runs every time, so it could be creating a new string object every time.

I read about string interning, so I’m curious how that plays into this.

Comment: "is it more efficient to...?" [race your horses!](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Why don't you test for yourself and see?

Comment: You may want to address the syntax typos in your posted code. Keywords ("class", "public") are lowercase, your properties do not have a return type, and you're using "smart quotes" rather than regular double quotes.

Comment: Truthfully I’m less concerned about efficiency in my application here, but was just thinking since strings are immutable it might cache. From what I’ve read, the answer is ‘maybe’ and was hoping for a clearer explanation of the behind-the scenes here. That, and I don’t quite know how to check to see what it’s doing at runtime as far as reusing the same string or not. I know stepping through it the function always runs, but don’t know how compiler may optimize (or not) this and was curios

Comment: @gunr2171 - yea that typo in the code was because I posted this using my phone I can fix all that once I’m back on a computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `=>` in this case is not a lambda, it's syntax sugar for a read-only property. It's equivalent to

```
public string FileFilter
{
    get
    {
        return String.Format("{0}{1}|{1}", Name, Extension);
    }
}
```

---

> If using the lambda expression several times in a row, are new instances created, or is it cached?

The getter in a property is evaluated each time it is read. This means if you call `FileFilter` multiple times, `String.Format` will run multiple times. The two values you use in `String.Format`, Name and Extension, can only be set by the constructor. This means that once the constructor has finished, `FileFilter` will return different string objects, but each object will have the same value, no mater how many times you read the property.

You *could* calculate and cache this value in the constructor after you set Name and Extension, or you can let this trivial amount of code stay as is. That's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I’ll leave it, since it is a trivial amount of code, and the string itself will be seldomly retrieved. So no use holding onto all them in static memory forever. If it were a high-use class, I think I’d calculate it out in the constructor. I was just curious if String.Format had some sort of pointer optimization that was occurring. Also, thanks for clarification on the syntactic sugar. I knew a lambda is ()=>, but I didn’t know that in place of a get its technically not  one.

Comment: Or, if it's costly and may never be called, you could use `Lazy<T>` to lazy evaluate the result, effectively caching it the first time it's called.  Create a private field: `private Lazy<string> _fileFilter = new Lazy<string>(()=>string.Format(“{0}{1}|{1}”, Name, Extension));` and then make your `FileFilter` property getter do this: `public string FileFilter => _fileFilter.Value;`

Comment: That doesn't answer whether the string is interned, but `string.Format` doesn't intern AFAIK